# Problem, how to stop reloading data on uitableview

Tags: objective-c

I am getting data from xml and display on table view via custom cells, so when i scroll it down above data hide and when i scroll up hide data display but again waiting for response from server for xml, so i do not want this my requirement is if data show tableview then it should save or remain there. Kindly help me.

Comment: Save the coming data locally in NSMutablArray.

Comment: i don't think so its smart solution, it should have some different way to solve...

Answer (score 0):

An object:

```
YourObject *yourObj = [[YourObject alloc] init];
yourObj.ID = 12121;
yourObj.Title = @"Some title";
```

An `NSMutableArray` containing your object:

```
NSMutableArray *dataSource = [NSMutableArray array];
[self.dataSource addObject:yourObj];
[yourObj release];
```

Within your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
YourObject *yourObj = (YourObj *)[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Then you can do the following to access properties from your object that's stored within the `dataSource` `NSMutableArray`:

```
cell.titleLabel.text = yourObj.Title;
```

Comment: Its good but i am also getting images from server side, so is this good approach to save images locally and it might b possible that thousands of images will be show, how can i handle images?